# SimplePie parsing huge XML file causes Memory Leak

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplepie

I'm using a very cool application called [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org), the problem with that is when I'm parsing this very huge XML file `http://feeds.feedburner.com/HubSpot`, which is about 10Mb in size, when it starts to parse, it suddenly breaks everything because it gets this error `Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14441498 bytes) in...`

Based on my research on the internet, it says you can cut the xml file and parse them one by one then process it through SimplePie then you won't get a Memory leaked or out of memory error, here is the [source of my research](http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/how_to_edit_part_of_the_feed_before_parsing_it?s%5B%5D=set&s%5B%5D=raw&s%5B%5D=data). I'm not sure how to do that one, Do you have any idea how to do that?

An example using the feed that I provided above would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help you any?  Checkmark please?

Comment: Sorry, but it did not help. :)

Comment: Actually, it perfectly explained how to fix your problem.  Thanks for wasting my time.